# remove trailing slash in nginx with some certain cases ignored

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following rewrite rule in my nginx:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

to remove trailing slash at the end of any URL. However I wanted to make an exception such that when the URL is `/register/` I don't want this rule to be applied. How do I put that into the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **Negative Lookahead**.

```
^/(?!register)(.*)/$
```

If you don't want `register` anywhere between such as `/exampleregister/`, use the following.

```
^/(?!.*register)(.*)/$
```