# regex nginx remove trailing slashes not apply to 2 folders?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

We want nginx to permanent redirect url's with a trailing slash to the non slash url. we found:
https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/nginx-remove-trailing-slash/

So we put:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$ permanent;
```

In the nginx, but the problem is it must not apply to some folders. so we found:
[remove trailing slash in nginx with some certain cases ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337134/remove-trailing-slash-in-nginx-with-some-certain-cases-ignored)

and we changed it to:

```
rewrite ^/(?!admin)(.*)/$ /$ permanent;
```

but then the server wouldn't start:

```
invalid number of arguments in "rewrite" directive in /opt/www/folder/.nginx:5
```

And: we want 2 folders excluded.
What is the right regex to exclude the folders from the rewrite rule?

Thanks,

Bart

Edit for who comes here by google:

The answer works... only strange thing is that the standard worked without the $1 :

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$ permanent;
```

and now we made the exclude, it didn't work anymore without the $1.... but this works for now:

```
# remove trailing slashes
rewrite ^/(?!folder1|folder2)(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is just a typo. That `/$` looks like it should be `/$1`:

```
rewrite ^/(?!admin)(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

If you have more that one URI to exclude, try something like

```
rewrite ^/(?!admin|secure|raw)(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

`nginx` uses the same regular expression library as Perl, so you can test this stuff from a command line with

```
perl -ple 's#^/(?!admin|secure|raw)(.*)/$#/$1#'
```

and just typing in example URIs.